# Get foreign key element from a related_name on django

Tags: django, foreign-keys, django-queryset

I have three models such as the one below and I am trying to write a query that allows me to access all the `Day_Type` associated to the `Day` objects that are pointing to a specific `JobProject`.

I know that I can get all the `Day` pointing at a `JobProject` by querying `project.jobproject_days.all()` and I can get the values of the `Day_Type` by doing `project.jobproject_days.values_list('day_type__name', flat=True)`

BUT how can I get the `Day_Type` themselves?

```
class JobProject(models.Model):
         ......

class Day_Type(models.Model):
         name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Day(models.Model):
      ....
      day_type = models.ForeignKey(Day_Type, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='day_type')
      project =  models.ForeignKey(JobProject, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='jobproject_days', null=True)
```

Comment: I know this can be a way but I am doing two queries and would like to avoid if possible. `Day_Type.objects.filter(id__in=project.jobproject_days.values_list('day_type',flat=True))`

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch it like this:

```
daytypes = Day_Type.objects.filter(day_type__project=project)
```